# EMF for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, emf

I have only just begun to learn EMF by following this tutorial:
What every Eclipse developer should know about EMF
(by Jonas Helming and Maximilian Koegel)

So, I downloaded an update to add EMF to my Eclipse. The file after extraction is called:

`emf-xsd-Update-2.8.3`

What do I do now? How do I install EMF on my IDE?

How do I specify to the IDE that it's there?!

(I have an Eclipse IDE for Java Developers [Juno on Mac] as well as e2m)

Thanks,

Comment: [This may help](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/emf-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. You download EMF as a set of eclispe plugins (i.e. JAR files), and you put them under the plugins/ or dropins/ directory from your Eclipse root directory
2. (EASIEST WAY) From Eclipse, Help -> Install new software -> [here you select an update site from which you can install the EMF plugins]

Here you find the update site for EMF:
http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/

You may also want to look at the EMF Installation wiki page:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF/Installation